# Type conversion in F# results in wrong type and wrong value

Tags: f#, type-conversion

I want to convert an integer to a float.

This is my first attempt and both, the value is wrong, 2 instead of 9, and also the type stayed `int`.

```
> a;;
val it: int = 9

> let b = (float)a;;
val b: int = 2
```

Can somebody please explain this?

P.S I managed to convert the integer to float with `let (b:float) = a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure this is what really happens? Are you sure you haven't mistyped anything? Maybe you redefined the `float` function somewhere above?

Because, you see, what you perceive as "type conversion" is not. F# doesn't have this C-style syntax of `(type) var` to "cast" or "convert" types. There is a concept of "type casting" in F# (operators `:>` and `:?>`), but it only works for subtypes and supertypes, which doesn't apply here.

What you're *actually* doing here is calling the `float` function and passing `a` as a parameter to it. Yes, `float` is the name of a function. And also name of a type. Types and functions can have same names, like in most other languages.

The function call syntax in F# is `fn arg` - just the function followed by a space and then followed by the argument. And the `fn` bit can be any expression that results in a function, it doesn't have to a straight up function name. For example, `(makeFunction 1 2 "foo") arg` also works, as long as the `makeFunction` function returns another function.

This means that surrounding the `float` function with parens has basically no effect. Writing `(float)a` is equivalent to `float a`.

And this works just as expected on my local machine:

```
- let a = 9
- let b = float a
- let c = (float)a;;
val a: int = 9
val b: float = 9.0
val c: float = 9.0
```

And same happens on replit.com - [check it out](https://replit.com/@FyodorSoikin/int-to-float#main.fs).

The only way I can think of that you may be getting your result is if somewhere *before*, but in the same FSI session, you have redefined the `float` function like this:

```
let float x = 2
```

This would indeed produce the result you're describing:

```
- let float x = 2
- let a = 9
- let b = float a
- let c = (float)a;;
val float: x: 'a -> int
val a: int = 9
val b: int = 2
val c: int = 2
```

Comment: Hi Fyodor, you are right. When I run the same commands in a new FSI window it works.